# trigger.io 2.1 and Android 4.4 - Error returning data from Java to JavaScript

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm having an issue on a Nexus 10, running Android 4.4.2.  When starting the app, the Forge console gives me several lines of the following:

```
[ERROR]  Error returning data from Java to JavaScript
```

In the initialisation of my app, I make use of calls like

```
forge.is.mobile();
forge.event.backPressed.preventDefault();
```

I'm wondering if the problem lies in getting the return values from these?

I have built the app in version 2.1 of Trigger.io, and have updated all the modules that are included in the project (contact, display, file, geolocation, icons, launchimage, prefs, request, ui)

This app plays nice with other Android versions that I have tested, including 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2

Comment: I'd suggest to debug each line of Javascript step by step in order to know which call is the malicious one.

Comment: Removing some of the lines in my init (mainly the `forge.event.backPressed.preventDefault();` one, and the associated block has stopped these messages from coming up.  The downside there, of course, is that I can no longer hook in to the device's back button behaviour.